# How do I validate an array model attribute against a set of possible values?

Tags: plugin-development, models, attribute

I have a need to set a property on a plugin Model that is an array of one or more valid values.

I can see that I can use AttributeType::Enum and record and define a set of values but if I'm not mistaken, that enables me to validate a single value against that set of values:

```
class MyModel extends BaseModel
{
    protected function defineAttributes()
    {
        return [
            'mySetting' => [ AttributeType::Enum, 'values' => 'validOption1,validOption2,validOption3' ]
        ];
     }
}
```

What I want to do is enable mySetting to be an array that would be valid when set as **an array containing any combination of the defined options**:

```
MyModel::populateModel(['mySetting' => [
    'validOption1'
]]); // is valid

MyModel::populateModel(['mySetting' => [
    'validOption1', 
    'validOption3'
]]); // is valid

MyModel::populateModel(['mySetting' => [
    'invalidOption', 
    'validOption3'
]]); // is *not* valid

MyModel::populateModel(['mySetting' => []); // is *not* valid
```

Etc.

Answer (score 4):

Found an answer in the form of a customer validator class on the model:

https://experiencehq.net/blog/the-definitive-guide-to-validation-in-craft-part-5-custom-validators#newsletter

So something like this:

```
    public function validateMySetting($attribute)
    {
        $values = (is_array($this->$attribute)) ? $this->$attribute : [ $this->$attribute ];

        $validValues = ['validOption1', 'validOption2', 'validOption3'];

        foreach($values as $value)
        {
            if ( ! in_array($value, $validValues))
            {
                $this->addError($attribute, "{$value} is not a valid setting");
            }
        }
    }
```

And then to call it, override the parent class' `rules` method:

```
public function rules ()
{
    return array_merge(parent::rules(), [ 
        'someAttributeName', 'validateMySetting'
    ];
}
```

Comment: It is not getting into my custom validator's callback function. How do I do that?

Comment: @Volatil3 I've updated the answer with details of how to add your custom validator method to the model's validation rules.